# How can i move a file from one folder to another in SharePoint using Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph Api to move a file from one folder to another in SharePoint.
I am trying to use the following:

```
 POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/copy
```

Is itemId the id of the destination folder ?
Is driveId the id of the file ?

I would of thought there would be an endpoint like something

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/root:/{folder-path}/{fileName}/copy](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroup-id%7D/drive/root:/%7Bfolder-path%7D/%7BfileName%7D/copy)
with a body as follows:

```
var parentReference = new ItemReference
{
    DriveId = "Destination Drive Id",
    Id = "Destination Folder Id"
};
```

Also what is the DriveId ?

Or is there another way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Drive` is the top-level object that represents a user's OneDrive or a document library in SharePoint.

`driveId` is the unique identifier of the drive.

`itemId` is the unique identifier of the file or folder.

There are two endpoints you can use.

If you want to move file to another folder but between the same `drive` (document library) you can use

```
PATCH /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
```

with request body.

```
{
  "parentReference": {
    "id": "{new-parent-folder-id}"
  },
  "name": "new-item-name.txt"
}
```

`drive-id` is the id of the source drive

`item-id` is the id of the file you want to move

`new-parent-folder-id` is the id of the destination folder

If you want to move file between two drive (document libraries) you can use

```
POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/copy
```

with request body

```
{
  "parentReference": {
    "driveId": "{new-drive-id}",
    "id": "{new-parent-folder-id}"
  },
  "name": "new-item-name.txt"
}
```

`drive-id` is the id of the source drive

`item-id` is the id of the file you want to move

`new-drive-id` is the id of the destination drive

`new-parent-folder-id` is the id of the destination folder

Resources:

[Move an item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Copy an item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)